# Shorting list by name - Angular 5 + Firebase

Tags: list, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have created a service where I get all the elements of my database:

**Service**

```
 getElements() {
    return (this.eleList= this.firebase.list("elements"));
  }
```

**Component**

```
eleList: Element[];
getBets() {
    return this.databaseService
      .getElements()
      .snapshotChanges()
      .subscribe(item => {
        this.eleList= [];
        item.forEach(element => {
          let x = element.payload.toJSON();
          x["$key"] = element.key;
          this.eleList.push(x as Element);
        });
      });
  }
```

With these two methods what I do is to store all my elements in `this.eleList`.

I would like to create a new method, named `filterByName(name)`, where I would update `this.eleList` to an array which contains only the ones that contain `name`in the object, for example, `this.eleList[1].name`

I do not know if Firebase provides a way to short it, or I need to use Javascript/Typescript for it.

Comment: Firebase will not return it in the sorted order. you need to use some map filters to achieve the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase takes full advantage of the observables and async pipes.

You should take advantage of that :

```
eleList$ = new Subject();

getElements() {
  this.this.firebase.list("elements")
    .pipe(take(1))
    .subscribe(list => this.eleList$.next(list));
}

getBets() {
  this.databaseService
    .getElements()
    .snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(
      map(item => items.map(element => ({
        ...element.payload.toJSON(),
        '$key': element.key
      })))
    )
    .subscribe(elements => this.eleList$.next(list));
}
```

Now for a sorted list :

```
sortedList$ = this.eleList$.pipe(
  map(elements => elements.filter(element => !!element.name))
);
```